# Python equivalent function of solve() in R

Tags: python, r, solver, equivalent

What equivalent function can I can in Python that is equivalent to `solve()` in R?

In R, if I call `solve(a, b)`, it will return me the `x` as in `a*x = b` where `a` is my covariance matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `np.linalg.solve`:

```py
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 5]])
>>> b = np.array([1, 2])
>>> x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
>>> x
array([-1.,  1.])
```

```r
> solve(matrix(c(1,2,3,5), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE), c(1, 2))
[1] -1  1
```

Comment: Just in case anyone is interested in the one-argument case where `a` is specified but `b` is not:  R's `solve` supports `solve(a)` (i.e., with no `b` argument) but `np.linalg.solve` does not. In this case the Python equivalent is `np.linalg.inv(a)`.